# Checkbox filtering using Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filtering

I'm using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/42/ to filter categories, however I need the functionality to be slightly different. If more than one filter is checked the item most contain both to be display.

Example:

Checking Category A and B would only display 'AB' not all instances of 'A' and 'B'

HTML:

```
<ul id="filters">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" />
    <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" />
    <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
</li>
```

```
<div class="item categorya categoryb">A, B</div>
<div class="item categorya">A</div>
<div class="item categorya">A</div>
<div class="item categorya">A</div>
<div class="item categoryb">B</div>
<div class="item categoryb">B</div>
<div class="item categoryb">B</div>
```

JS:

```
    $("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

   var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                          return this.value;
                       }).get().join("|") );
   $(".item").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this[re.source!="" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a regular expression for this. Instead you can `join()` the array you create with `map()` by a `.` to build a class selector which you can then use to directly show the required elements. Try this:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" />
        <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" />
        <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="category-container">
    <div class="categorya categoryb">A, B</div>
    <div class="categorya">A</div>
    <div class="categorya">A</div>
    <div class="categorya">A</div>
    <div class="categoryb">B</div>
    <div class="categoryb">B</div>
    <div class="categoryb">B</div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var filter = '.' + $("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(".");

    $('.category-container div').hide();
    $(filter).show();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/1189/)

> How would you modify it to show all by default until options are checked?

To do that you could just check if anything was selected and show all options if not. Firstly remove `display: none` from `.categorya, .categoryb`, then amend the JS to this:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var filter = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(".");

    if (filter) {
        $('.category-container div').hide();
        $('.' + filter).show();
    } else {
        $('.category-container div').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you modify it to show all by default until options are checked? Currently if you deselect all options nothing appears. It makes sense to default to all unless options are checked

Comment: To do that you could just check if anything was selected and show all options if not. I updated my answer, although can't show you a working example as jsFiddle is not working correctly at the moment.